# Extracting numbers from a string including decimels and scientific notation

Tags: regex, r

I have some strings that look like

```
x<-"p = 9.636e-05"
```

And I would like to extract just the number using gsub. So far I have

```
gsub("[[:alpha:]](?!-)|=|\\^2", "", x)
```

But that removes the 'e' from the scientific notation, giving me

```
"  9.636-05"
```

Which can't be converted to a number using as.numeric. I know that it would be possible to use a lookahead to match the "-", but I don't know exactly how to go about doing this.

Comment: Try `sub('.* ', '', x)#[1] "9.636e-05"`

Comment: Do you have any other patterns in the string

Comment: Other patterns in my strings are "slope=" and "R^2="

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following to initially remove all non-digit characters at the start of the string:

```
sub('^\\D+', '', x)
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm sure there are many ways of solving this problem but this is the solution I'm going to use

Comment: @CactusWoman but this one wont work for your r**2 case: `x<-"R^2 = .6"; sub('^\\D+', '', x)` you get `[1] "2 = .6"` @akrun's will though

Comment: @rawr I modified it a bit to '^\\D+|2 ='

Comment: @rawr, if OP needs that type replaced as well .. `.* ` is fine.

Answer (score 4):

You could try

```
 sub('.* = ', '', x)
 #[1] "9.636e-05"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
format(as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9e.-]", "", x)), scientific = FALSE)
# [1] "0.00009636"
```

Answer (score 1):

Through sub or regmatches function.

```
> x<-"p = 9.636e-05"
> sub(".* ", "", x)
[1] "9.636e-05"
> regmatches(x, regexpr("\\S+$", x))
[1] "9.636e-05"
> library(stringi)
> stri_extract(x, regex="\\S+$")
[1] "9.636e-05"
```